# Is there a way to dynamically change the model used in an UpdateView with Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

The application I'm writing includes a pipeline for creating events. An `Event` is proposed by one class of users, then approved and edited by administrators. The problem for me is that there is a subclass of `Event`, `ScoredEvent`, which the administrators should be able to specify on-the-fly. This adds a `ScoredEvent.competition` foreign key and overrides the `Event.participants` to put them through a table that includes an associated score for each participant.

Ideally, a normal user creates an event containing only the name and a short description (easy enough to do by limiting the fields on the non-admin CreateEventForm) then the admins can go back in and fill out the other fields when they are approving the event.

The problem I'm hitting is I don't know how it would be possible for an administrator to change an `Event` to a `ScoredEvent` in the approval form view when they are editing it or how to make that happen. My vision of the page is an edit view with a checkbox labeled "Tie To Competition" that, when checked, would allow the admin to select a competition and then save the event as a `ScoredEvent`. If that box weren't checked, the event would continue it's life as an `Event`.

Where should this be handled? My gut feeling is that I should do something special in the forms.py or something in the Templates, but I don't know where I should begin.

```
class Event(models.Model):                                                       
    """Representation of any community event"""                                  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique_for_date="start_datetime")     
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=57) # length +7 for datestamp             
    description = models.TextField()                                             
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)                      
    start_datetime = models.DateTimeField('Start', blank=True)                   
    end_datetime = models.DateTimeField('End', blank=True)                       
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(Participant)                                                                                            

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):                                             
        if not self.slug:                                                        
            self.slug = slugify(self.name)+'-'+datetime.now().strftime("%d%m%y") 
        super(Event, self).save(*args, **kwargs)                                 

    def __unicode__(self):                                                       
        if self.start_datetime:                                                       
            return "%s (%s)" % (self.name, self.start_datetime.date())           
        else:                                                                    
            return self.name                                                     

class ScoredEvent(Event):                                                        
    """Representation of an event that is tied to a competition"""               
    competition = models.ForeignKey(Competition)                                 
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(Participant, through="ScoredParticipant")

    def is_scored(self):                                                         
        """Returns true if any of the participants has a score, else returns false"""
        for participant in self.participants.objects.all():                              
            if participant.score != 0:                                           
                return False                                                     
        return True                                                              

class ScoredPartcipant(models.Model):                                            
    """Participant and associated score for an event"""                          
    participant = models.ForeignKey(Participant)                                 
    event = models.ForeignKey(ScoredEvent)                                                                                                               
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Comment: You need a foreign key from `ScoredEvent` to the normal `Event`, then admin creates a `ScoredEvent` linked to the normal `Event` that the user populates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override `get_queryset` and vary on whether one of the fields is posted:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    if self.request.POST.has_key('competition'):
        return ScoredEvent.objects.all()
    else:
        return super(MyView, self).get_queryset()
```

So, just to explain a little better: you would use your "Tie to Competition" option you mentioned to add a field to the form via Javascript. Then, if the field is sent in the POST, it would switch to using `ScoredEvent` instead.

If you want to automatically switch based on what the object currently is, you'd need to override `get_object` for that. Something along the lines of:

```
def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    obj = super(MyView, self).get_object(queryset=queryset)
    try:
        return ScoredEvent.objects.get(pk=obj.pk)
    except ScoredEvent.DoesNotExist:
        return obj
```

Which basically tries to lookup the object again as if it was a `ScoredEvent` and returns that version if it finds one, instead of `Event`.

You also might need to similarly override `get_form_class` to ensure that it validates as a `ScoredEvent` should if it's a `ScoredEvent` or is becoming a `ScoredEvent`:

```
from django.forms import models as model_forms

def get_form_class(self):
    if isinstance(self.object, ScoredEvent):
        return model_forms.modelform_factory(ScoredEvent, ScoredEventForm)
    else:
        return super(MyView, self).get_form_class()
```

Comment: So, if I'm understanding this correctly, the event remains an `Event` unless the admin specifies a competition fk, in which case it becomes a `ScoredEvent`. Is that correct?